# Link Data JPA / Hibernate entities not using id field

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I would like to link 2 entities but using a column that is not a primary key (and not marked with @Id in the class file).

```
@Entity
class MediaLog(
    @Id
    var id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
    var caseSystemId: String,
    var articleSummary: String?,
    var totalArticleCount: Int,
    var resolvedAt: Instant? = null,
    var lastCheckPerformedAt: Instant? = null
)

@Entity
@Audited
class CustomerCase(
    @Id
    var id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
    var authAccountId: UUID,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var status: CaseStatus,
    var caseSystemId: String? = null
)
```

The relationship is OneToOne and they should be linked using the `caseSystemId`. The `MediaLog` MUST have a valid CustomerCase to link to it, but a there might be situations where some `CustomerCase` doesn't have any `MediaLog` entries. And yes, the `MediaLog` is not audited while the `CustomerCase` is audited (but that's not a problem).

I've tried all the possible combications of using @OneToOne and @JoinColumn, and playing with properties of each annotation but can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you did try so far, but the following should work just fine:

```
@Entity
class MediaLog(
    @Id
    var id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "caseSystemId", referenceColumnName = "caseSystemId")
    var customerCase: CustomerCase,
    var articleSummary: String?,
    var totalArticleCount: Int,
    var resolvedAt: Instant? = null,
    var lastCheckPerformedAt: Instant? = null
)

@Entity
@Audited
class CustomerCase(
    @Id
    var id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
    var authAccountId: UUID,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var status: CaseStatus,
    @Column(name = "caseSystemId", unique = true)
    var caseSystemId: String? = null
)
```

Comment: I tried like that but then I'm getting `cannot be cast to class java.io.Serializable` so then I would need ti implement these interfaces in these classes which I don't think is the best solution

Comment: No idea where you are getting this exception. Please share the stack trace if you seek further help